# How to set the ProcessFlowLaneHeader state with JSON-model?

Tags: sapui5

i'm currently working on an SAPUI5 app which includes a Process Flow control.
I want to set the state of the ProcessFlowLaneHeader according to values in my JSON-model but it keeps changing to a state represting each existing state of the nodes.
So I want the "donut" to show 2/3 of green, 1/12 of grey and 1/4 of red color(see JSON below). Instead it shows me 1/3 of each. When I look at the properties of the ProcessFlowLaneHeader through the UI5 Inspector while the app is running it shows me:

```
state: {
0: {
  "state": "Positive",
  "value": 1
}
1: {
  "state": "Negative",
  "value": 1
}
2: {
  "state": "Neutral",
  "value": 1
}
3: {
  "state": "Planned",
  "value": 0
}
4: {
  "state": "Critical",
  "value": 0
}
```

Did i make a mistake or is SAUPUI5 just overwriting my state?
How can I set the state of the ProcessFlowLaneHeade?(onInit on controller?)

My JSON:

```
...
"lanes": [{
    "id": "0",
    "icon": "sap-icon://sales-quote",
    "label": "MoBe",
    "position": 0,
    "state": [{
        "state": "Positive",
        "value": 8
    }, {
        "state": "Negative",
        "value": 1
    }, {
        "state": "Neutral",
        "value": 3
    }, {
        "state": "Planned",
        "value": 0
    }, {
        "state": "Critical",
        "value": 0
    }]
},
...
```

My View:

```
<ProcessFlow id="processflow1" foldedCorners="false" wheelZoomable="false" class="PFLayoutSpec" nodes="{Monitor1>/nodes}" lanes="{Monitor1>/lanes}">
    <nodes>
        <ProcessFlowNode laneId="{Monitor1>lane}" nodeId="{Monitor1>id}" title="{Monitor1>title}" children="{Monitor1>children}" state="{Monitor1>state}" value="{Monitor1>value}" stateText="{Monitor1>stateText}" texts="{Monitor1>texts}" highlighted="{Monitor1>highlighted}" focused="{Monitor1>focused}" titleAbbreviation="{Monitor1>titleAbbreviation}"/>
    </nodes>
    <lanes>
        <ProcessFlowLaneHeader laneId="{Monitor1>id}" iconSrc="{Monitor1>icon}" text="{Monitor1>label}" position="{Monitor1>position}" state="{Monitor1>state}" press="onChangeDonut"/>
    </lanes>
</ProcessFlow>
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Because you are showing documents in the `nodes` aggregation, the `ProcessFlowLaneHeader` state is automatically calculated from the states of the documents.

See [documentation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.suite.ui.commons.ProcessFlowLaneState):

> This type is used in the 'state' property of the ProcessFlowLaneHeader. For example, app developers can set the status of the lane header if lanes are displayed without documents. If the complete process flow is displayed (that is, if the lane header is displayed with documents underneath), the given state values of the lane header are ignored and will be calculated in the ProcessFlow according to the current state of the documents.